# Extract Ruby Back trace message fields using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

**Ruby back trace message :**

```
["/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:19:in `sampleRailsNullPointerException'", 
"/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'"]
```

*Note : There are no newline on ruby back trace message.*

**Expected Match:**

```
/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
19
sampleRailsNullPointerException
```

---

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb
4
send_action
```

I tried to design regex :

```
^(?P<path>[^:]*):(?P<line>\d+):in\s+`(?P<exception>\w+)$
```

But this regex didn't match with the requirement.

Comment: What do you need to match exacly ? Do you just want to separate each part of the backtrace message ?

Comment: I converted the regex to `[\[]?(?P<path>[^:^`]*):(?P<line>\d+):in\s+`(?P<exception>\w+)'",[\]]?`

Now it matches 

path "/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
line 19
exception sampleRailsNullPointerException

Comment: Why not use `Exception#backtrace_locations` (returns an array of `Thread::Backtrace::Location` instances)?

Comment: Actually, I'm developing log parser for the different type of language like java, ruby, javascript using Java. 

So, I required regex to extract exception fields from exception message.

Answer (score 0):

```
re = /^(?<path>[^:]*):(?<line>\d+):in\s+`(?<exception>\w+)'$/

trace = [
  "/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:19:in `sampleRailsNullPointerException'", 
  "/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'"
]

trace.map { |line| re.match(line).captures }
# => [["/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb", "19", "sampleRailsNullPointerException"], ["/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb", "4", "send_action"]]
```

You forgot the closing quote before the end of the line; also, I don't know what you meant with the `(?P...)`.

Comment: Yeah me neither, I never saw this `P<something>` syntax in regular expressions before.

Comment: `(?P<name>regex)` is the syntax for named groups in Python, PCRE, R, among others ("P" is for Python, where named groups was first implemented). However, it's not supported by Ruby. For named groups in Ruby, either `(?<name>re)` or `(?'name're)`

Comment: @Mariano: Yeah, Ruby doesn't use PCRE, but Oniguruma, which does not use `(?P...)`.

Comment: Hey @Mariano, Can you help me?

This regex [\[\,\"]*(\/[^:]+?):(\d+):in\s+`(\w+)'"\]?  parse everything which required. It fails when test string is like


["/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process'"]


Because of space in `block in process`. Regex doesn't match the string.

Comment: @Amit Change `\w+` to `[^']+` **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kE8sJ3/3)**... And next time, please **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33666730/edit)** your question with proper code formatting

Comment: Thank You @Mariano.

I will take care about formatting.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
s = "/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:19:in `sampleRailsNullPointerException'"
m = s.match(/^([^:]+?):(\d+):in\s+`(\w+)'$/)
m[1] #=> "/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb"
m[2] #=> "19"
m[3] #=> "sampleRailsNullPointerException"
```

Comment: If the backtrace message is 


["/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:19:in `sampleRailsNullPointerException'", 
"/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'", 
"/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'"]


Then it gives the result like

["/home/ec2-user/LogglyRails/RailsApp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

Comment: oh ok, the quote before the third match isn't always here. Then use the regex : /^([^:]+?):(\d+):in\s+`?(\w+)'$/

Comment: I added a "?" after the quote before the third match, to specify that this quote is optional. I just edited my answer with it

Comment: Oh no, it was the stakoverflow markdown which suppressed the "`" character... Then what is different with you examples ?

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is your array, you could write:

```
arr.map do |s|
  first,mid,last = s.split(/(:\d+:in\s*)/)
  [first, mid.gsub(/\D+/,'').to_i, last]
end
```